# validate string in java

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string with data separated by commas like this:

```
$d4kjvdf,78953626,10.0,103007,0,132103.8945F,
```

I tried the following regex but it doesn't match the strings I want:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,
```

Comment: What defines a valid or invalid string?

Comment: @dimo414 number of commas

Comment: So *any* letters, other than commas, are allowed?

Comment: yes any letters other than commas allowed

Comment: Does your string need to have comma at the end? Or I will ask differently: is position of commas relevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your regular expression is certainly jarbled - there are clearly characters (like `$` and `.`) that your expression won't match, and you don't need to `\\` escape `,`s.  Lets first describe our requirements, you seem to be saying a valid string is defined as:

> A string consisting of 6 commas, with one or more characters before each one

We can represent that with the following pattern:

```
(?:[^,]+,){6}
```

This says match one or more non-commas, followed by a comma - `[^,]+,` - six times - `{6}`.  The `(?:...)` notation is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group), which lets us say match the whole sub-expression six times, without it, the `{6}` would only apply to the preceding character.

---

Alternately, we could use normal, capturing groups to let us select each individual section of the matching string:

```
([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),?
```

Now we can not only match the string, but extract its contents at the same time, e.g.:

```
String str = "$d4kjvdf,78953626,10.0,103007,0,132103.8945F,";
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile(
  "([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),([^,]+),?");
Matcher m = regex.matcher(str);

if(m.matches()) {
  for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
    System.out.println(m.group(i));
  }
}
```

This prints:

> ```
> $d4kjvdf
> 78953626
> 10.0
> 103007
> 0
> 132103.8945F
> ```

Answer (score 2):

The `$` at the beginning of your data string is not matching the regex. Change the first character class to `[$a-zA-Z0-9]`. And a couple of the comma separated values contain a literal dot. `[$.a-zA-Z0-9]` would cover both cases. Also, it's probably a good idea to anchor the regex at the start and end by adding `^` and `$` to the beginning and end of the regex respectively. How about this for the full regex:

```
^[$.a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[$.a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[$.a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[$.a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[$.a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,[$.a-zA-Z0-9]+\\,$
```

### Update:

You said number of commas is your primary matching criteria. If there should be 6 commas, this would work:

```
^([^,]+,){6}$
```

That means: match at least 1 character that is anything but a comma, followed by a comma. And perform the aforementioned match 6 times consecutively. Note: your data must end with a trailing comma as is consistent with your sample data.